# Unsure where to put code in program. An how to have circles generated on touch in XCode. (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, drawing

Program used: XCode

Language: Objective-C

What I am Trying to do: Create a program that creates a circle centered on a touch with a random diameter.

Below in dashes I have what code I have to create a circle of random diameter in my UIView. I am basically a beginner so I am flat out unsure where to actually put this code inside the program file (viewcontroller, scenedelegate, etc). I also am unsure how to go about creating the code to have this be done on a screen touch.

Any help or tips is greatly appreciated.

```
float rndValue = (((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*47);


CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, rndValue, rndValue)] CGPath]];


[[self.view layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];


[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: That's not how we present code here

Comment: how do I do so then, haven't posted code before?

Edit- I found the tool to do so, thank you for informing me to format it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a code block manipulating `CALayer` should be put in `UIView` subclasses, although it also can be put in `[UIViewController viewDidLoad:]` or other places.

For example, a view which draws a circle in random position would be like the following:

```objectivec
#import "RandomCircleView.h"

@implementation RandomCircleView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self configureSublayers];
    }
    return self;
}

// MARK: Private

- (void)configureSublayers {
    float rndValue = (((float)arc4random()/0x100000000)*47);
    CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, rndValue, rndValue)] CGPath]];
    [self.layer addSublayer:circleLayer]; // ! this line is modified
    [circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
}

@end
```

Then you can add that view in your view controller like

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RandomCircleView *randomCircleView = [[RandomCircleView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:randomCircleView];
    // You may want to adjust the frame of randomCircleView here...
}
```

You can also use `RandomCircleView` in .xib and .storyboard files by specifying Custom Class.